# Spark SQL Query on DSE Cassandra in Scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to test the Spark-SQL query on DSE Cassandra table in Scala IDE. The query runs flawlessly when the jar file is executed in dse spark-submit.
But it gives an error when it runs in Scala IDE.
The error is,

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `killr_video`.`videos`; line 1 pos 14;

I think it's the spark master configuration error as I am running the master in local mode.

Here is the spark session I initiated.

```
val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("CassandraSpark")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
          .enableHiveSupport()
          .master("local")
          .getOrCreate();
```

But I don't know what address to set as master. I tried setting master address as "spark://127.0.0.1:7077" which I found from Web UI (localhost:7080) when I started Cassandra. But still, it gave an error as follows

> ERROR MapOutputTrackerMaster: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
>       java.lang.InterruptedException
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:212)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:222)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
>           at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
>           at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
>           at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:81)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:102)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:78)
>           at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:100)
>           at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.sendTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:110)
>           at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster.stop(MapOutputTracker.scala:580)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:84)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$11.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1797)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1290)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1796)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.StandaloneSchedulerBackend.dead(StandaloneSchedulerBackend.scala:142)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint.markDead(StandaloneAppClient.scala:254)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:131)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       18/05/22 11:46:44 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread appclient-registration-retry-thread
>       org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
>           at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:104)
>           at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.sendTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:110)
>           at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster.stop(MapOutputTracker.scala:580)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:84)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$11.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1797)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1290)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1796)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.StandaloneSchedulerBackend.dead(StandaloneSchedulerBackend.scala:142)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint.markDead(StandaloneAppClient.scala:254)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:131)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:212)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:222)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
>           at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
>           at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
>           at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:81)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:102)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:78)
>           at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:100)
>           ... 16 more
>       18/05/22 11:46:44 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:546)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2258)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
>       18/05/22 11:46:44 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:546)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2258)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)

What can I do to make this code work?

Comment: Are you using DSE Analytics or your own Spark? Do you see this table in cqlsh?

Comment: Yes this node is Analytics node. And same query works on dse spark-sql as well as cqlsh

Comment: can you start `dse spark` & execute your `spark.sql` query without creating the SparkSession instance?

Comment: Yes I can start dse spark & execute spark.sql query without creating the SparkSession instance but I want to be able to do it in Scala IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hardcode Cassandra IPs, or master - just create SparkSession object, and it will work. Here is working code (in Java):

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("CassandraSpark")
  .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql("select * from test.t1 limit 1000");
sqlDF.printSchema();
sqlDF.show();
```

In DSE, if you're submitting to distributed cluster, you can specify master as `dse://?`, and DSE will find current master automatically.  All [possible options are described in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/startingSpark.html#startingSpark__specifying-spark-urls).